# Map specific colour to specific variable on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create several PCA plots for different experiments. For each plot, i want the same colour point for each variable. So in my ggplot, i use scale_colour_manual and assign a list of colours in the order of the samples, however, these seem to randomly assign to each variable (grey is first colour listed and should map to cells as this is the first variable, but it doesnt. Code is below:

````
cisr5_plot <- ggplot(cisr5scores, aes(x=PC1, y=PC2))+
 geom_point(size= 4, aes(col=cisr5$Treatment))+
 scale_colour_manual(breaks=c("Cells","HIV-1 R5", "LPS", "M. bovis", "H37Rv", "HN878", "CDC1551", "EU127"),
                     values=c("grey","blue","red","orange","green","purple","yellow","pink"))+
 xlab(paste("PC1 ", "(",cisr5exp12[1],"%", sep=""))+
 ylab(paste("PC1 ", "(",cisr5exp12[2],"%", sep=""))+
 theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 24, family = "sans"),
       legend.position = "bottom",
       legend.text = element_text(size = 22, family = "sans"),
       axis.text.x = element_text(colour ="black", size = 22, family = "sans"),
       axis.text.y = element_text(colour ="black", size = 22, family = "sans"),
       axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "black", size = 24, family = "sans"),
       legend.title = element_blank(),
       panel.background = element_blank(),
       axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
       plot.title = element_text(size = 10, hjust = 0.5))+
 theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white")) ```

Any help would be appreciated!
````

Comment: Try with a named color vector, i.e. `values = c("Cells" = "grey", ....)`

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
d_colors <- data.frame(Treatment =c("Cells", "HIV-1 R5", "LPS", "M. bovis", 
                                    "H37Rv", "HN878", "CDC1551", "EU127"),
                       colTreatment=c("grey", "blue", "red", "orange",
                                      "green", "purple", "yellow", "pink"))


cisr5scores %>% 
  left_join(d_colors, by = "Treatment") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=PC1, y=PC2))+
  geom_point(size= 4, aes(col=colTreatment)) +
  scale_colour_identity()
```